# Program to read CSV and assign variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
with open('example.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    l = list(reader)
ld=len(l) #calculates the length downwards
    for i in range(0,ld): #the length downwards
    #for j in range(0,1): #the length  sidewards        
    a=l[i][0]

#plain_1 = "1weqweqd"
#plain_2 = "23444444"
#plain_3 = "dddd2225"
   .
   .
   .
```

How to assign values read from CSV file to variable in a loop? There may be more data.

example.csv

```
"1weqweqd"
"23444444"
"dddd2225"
```

Can someone solve the problem?

Comment: *What* problem? Please give a [mcve].

Comment: i have a python code which converts plain text to cipher ,now i want to read the plain text from CSV file and assign it to different variables such as plaintext1,plaintext2,...and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You should store all the data in a list instead of separate variables.

```
data = []
with open('example.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(line)
```

then you can access or loop over them for any thing you want to do for processing.

```
for i in data:
    #do something
    print i
print data[0]
```

Comment: now the data from the CSV is in list ->data , now i want that values in list to be assigned with variables depending on the size of list.

Comment: there is no need to store the values in independent values, it is more efficient to leave it in the list, you can think that the data is stored in variables `data[0], data[1], ... data[i]... data[n]`